# Making a time-efficient recursive fibonaccci algorithm using an arrayList

Tags: java, recursion, arraylist, fibonacci

I'm working on an assignment: a recursive method to determine the nth value of the Fibonacci sequence. The method is supposed to be more time-efficient by using an arrayList to store the calculated values, and every time I need to use a previously calculated value (e.g. n-1, n-2), it instead pulls the value from the arrayList, with O(1) access.

I can't quite figure out the recursion segment that creates and stores the values new to the arrayList.

```
private static class Fib3 implements Fibber
{
  private ArrayList<Integer> f = new ArrayList<Integer>();

  public int fib(int n){
     f.add(0);
     fiv(n);
     return f.get(f.size()-1);
  }
  private int fiv(int n){
     if(n == 1 || n == 2){
        f.add(1);
     }
     else{
        if(n < f.size()){
           return f.get(n);
        }
        else{
           f.add(fiv(n-1) + fiv(n-2));
           //return something here
        }
     } 
     //or here    
  }
```

}

What would I return in the commented lines?

Thanks

Comment: If it has to be "time-efficient", why are you using recursion?

Comment: It appears that you're asking us to write the entire upgrade.  What have you tried?  What have you figured out so far?  Why aren't the on-line resources any help to you?  Look for "dynamic programming" and/or "memoization".

Comment: @Jerfov2 The assignment is just using recursion and iterations and various data structures to complete the same task, I have the other variations down, this is just the one I'm having trouble with. The actual most efficient one is iterative and an array, this is just a variation I have to complete.

Comment: Does it have to be arraylist?  it makes more sense to use an array int[] or hashmap.

Comment: @Prune I tried already looking around online, and didn't really find anything that dealt with what I was looking for. I understand the concepts of dynamic programming, and memoization to an extent. I just need help with the application in this scenario. I've tried returning f.get(n), but I just get arrayOutOfBounds, so I'm really just wondering what I would return in that area, or at least what's wrong with the structure of my recursion.

Comment: @NickZiebert  There was a variation of this that I already complete using both and array and a hashMap, and those were fairly easy. I'm really only having trouble with the arrayList implementation of it.

Comment: Got it.  I looked more carefully at the code, and now I see what you thought you were trying to do with the memoization.  I didn't recognize it on first scan, because you failed to store the key (value of n) -- therefore, you couldn't recover the value at will, and I didn't ... well, I said that.  Elliot caught and corrected the problem.  I've voted to reopen the question.

Comment: I also made minor edits in the wording, which allowed me to reverse my down-vote.

Answer (score 2):

Your memoization is a little over complicated. When you declare and initialize `f` (and please program to the `List` interface, and you can use the Diamond Operator `<>`), you can add your two initial values like

```
private List<Integer> f = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(0, 1));
```

Then `fib` can check if the number is already available in `f` (return it if it is) and otherwise calculate the next value and store and then return it (`fiv` is doing all the work, but I think `fib` should be). Like,

```
public int fib(int n) {
    if (n < f.size()) {
        return f.get(n);
    }
    int v = fib(n - 2) + fib(n - 1);
    f.add(n, v);
    return v;
}
```

Actually calculating Fibonacci numbers can be done much faster in practice using φ (phi); aka the [Golden ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio#Relationship_to_Fibonacci_sequence).

Comment: I thought SO wasn't for people to do other peoples homework assignments.

Comment: Thank you! I looked at this and realized I'd overcomplicated my recursive statement with unnecessary conditions, and that I was adding calculated values to the arrayList in the wrong way.

Comment: Yeah, that's a good solution though.

Comment: @Nick This is largely OP's code. I removed more than I added.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Ya, that's a good point.  I'd take back my downvote if I could.

Comment: @NickZiebert Added a little note about φ. φ is O(1). We like O(1).

Answer (score 0):

Just write a plain Fibonacci as you would without the List. 
Then add List parts:

- when you enter your function, check if result is in the List, and return it if it is.
- whenever you return from function, store the result into list before returning.

Comment: Alright I'll try rewriting my code like that

Answer (score 0):

1. check base condition
2. check if fib(n) is in list.  If not, add it.
3. return fib.get(n)

It looks like this is what you're trying to accomplish.

You're code is really close to working.  Get rid of that first else, making things confusing.  Also, get rid of that helper function, not needed either.  Can add it back later once it's working.  Your edge condition should be returning 1.

Comment: I rewrote my code and got rid of some of the conditionals. Thank you! My code works and is a lot cleaner.